# Using nodejs server with request package and function pipe()?

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-stream, node-request

I'm using a nodejs server to mockup a backend at the moment. The server is a webserver and returns json objects on different requests, works flawlessy. Now I have to get the json objects from another domain, so I have to proxy the server. I have found a package called [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) in npm. I can get the simple example to work, but I have to forward the whole webpage.

My code for the proxy looks like this:

```
var $express = require('express'),
$http = require('http'),
$request = require('request'),
$url = require('url'),
$path = require('path'),
$util = require('util'),
$mime = require('mime');

var app = $express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 9090);
  app.use($express.bodyParser());
  app.use($express.methodOverride());

  app.use('/', function(req, res){
    var apiUrl = 'http://localhost:9091';
    console.log(apiUrl);
    var url = apiUrl + req.url;
    req.pipe($request(url).pipe(res));
  });  
});

$http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));

  if (process.argv.length > 2 && process.argv.indexOf('-open') > -1) {
    var open = require("open");
    open('http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '/', function (error) {
      if (error !== null) {
        console.log("Unable to lauch application in browser. Please install 'Firefox' or 'Chrome'");
      }
    });
  }
})
```

I'm loggin the real server and it is acting correctly, I can track the get response, but the body is empty. I just want to pass through the whole website from the nodejs server through the request.pipe function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in Node.js, `a.pipe(b)` returns `b` (see [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)), your code is equivalent to this:

```
// req.pipe($request(url).pipe(res))
// is equivalent to
$request(url).pipe(res);
req.pipe(res);
```

As you only want a proxy there is no need to pipe `req` into `res` (and here it doesn't make sense to pipe multiple readable streams into one writable stream), just keep this and your proxy will work:

```
$request(url).pipe(res);
```