# Heroku connection error (H13) when using proxy on secure server with express app

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, proxy

I am trying to set up a proxy on my express app to pass GET requests from http://www.example.com/blog to http://example.news .

I have used the following article to set it up
[Using nodejs server with request package and function pipe()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296571/using-nodejs-server-with-request-package-and-function-pipe)

So my code looks like this:

```
app.use('/blog', function(req, res) {
    var url = "http://example.news" + req.url;
    var options={url:url,timeout: 12000};
    request(options,function (err,preq,pres){
        if(err) res.redirect(url);
    }).pipe(res);
});
```

If there is an error, I redirect to the actual website.

It is working fine but The problem is I often get h13 connection error when I do the following:

```
var url = "https://example.news" + req.url;
```

The exact errors are:

```
{ [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
```

These errors mostly happen when the server first starts but it happens randomly.
Does anybody know the proper configuration to proxy a secure server with express and request? and why I get theses errors.